# Summing specific data from column in r

Tags: r, loops, sum

Im trying to creat a function in r that will let me sum data from the last three rows into a new column (i.e. if im looking at day 4 = days 3+2+1)

This is what i've worked out so far, however it doesnt work.

```
S3<- function(x){
res <- numeric(nrow(x))
for (i in 1:nrow(x)){    
res[i] <- i
if (i > 3) {             
  res[i] <- x[i-3,10]
} else {
  res[i] <- x[i,10]
}
}
x$PP3 <- res
return(x)
}
```

Comment: There's no line in your code that actually sums the last three rows. Also what is `res[i] <- i` there for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
x$PP3 <- x[,10] + c(0,head(x[,10],-1)) + c(0,0,head(x[,10],-2))
```

If you want a function:

```
S3 <- function(x, j=10){
    within(x, PP3 <- x[,j] + c(0,head(x[,j],-1)) + c(0,0,head(x[,j],-2)))
}
```